# Display array in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a list that has three columns; `menu`, `menuItem`, and `order`.

I want to display `menu` and `menuItem` by `order` like this example:

```
Menu 1 : order 200
Menu 2 : order 230
Menu 3 : order 250 
Menu item 1 : order 210
Menu item 2 : order 360
```

The result will be :

- Menu 1 have menu item 1 ( 200< 210 <230)
- Menu 2 : don't have menu item
- Menu 3 have menu item 2 ( because 250 < 360).

I do that in two lists (one for the menu and one for the item menu ) and when the value for item is between the menu index 1 and last menu index 2, I save it in a new list to display. But I have a problem with the new list: I can't have the value for every menu.

Can anyone could help me?

````
For(I=0; I< list1.length ;I++){
 let nextMenu = list1.order[I+1];
 for (j=0;j<list2.length ;j++){
  let item = list2[j].order;
  let menu = list1[I].order;
 if(menu < item < Next menu){
 This.list3.push(list2[j]);
  }
}
}
```![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TjDE.jpg)
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to treat the last item separately.

For instance, try in this way (you can refactor code in a better way, is just an example):

(I leave you [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qdn5bg?file=src/app/app.component.ts) a stackblitz with the code working in order you to test it)

```
...
// adding attibute class for the lists
  list1 = [];
  list2 = [];
  list3 = [];

const list1 = [
      { menu: 1, order: 200 },
      { menu: 2, order: 230 },
      { menu: 3, order: 250 },
    ];

    const list2 = [
      { item: 1, order: 210 },
      { item: 2, order: 360 },
    ];

    let list3 = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
      const next = i + 1;

      if (next <= list1.length - 1) {

        let nextMenu = list1[next].order;

        for (let j = 0; j < list2.length; j++) {

          let item = list2[j].order;
          let menu = list1[i].order;

          if (menu < item && item < nextMenu) {
            list3.push(list2[j]);
          }
        }
      } else {

        for (let j = 0; j < list2.length; j++) {

          let item = list2[j].order;
          let menu = list1[i].order;

          if (menu < item) {
            list3.push(list2[j]);
          }
        }

      }
    }

    this.list1 = list1;
    this.list2 = list2;
    this.list3 = list3;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let menu of list1">
    {{ 'Menu ' + menu.menu + ' : order  ' + menu.order }}
  </li>
  <li *ngFor="let item of list3">
    {{ 'Menu item ' + item.item + ' : order  ' + item.order }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT:
As you say that don't know well how to treat the result in you HTML, I edit my answer adding the HTML code (and adding attributes list for the HTML), whit your desired result, as you can see in this image:

[image]

I update the **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qdn5bg?file=src/app/app.component.html)** as well.

Comment: Yes i get the list3 by order but I have a problem to display it properly like : menu 1 ( item for menu 1) in HTML  <ul> menu1 <li> item1 </li></ul> I have always all the list 3 in <li>, this is my code in HTML : <div *ng for="let menu of list1">{{menu}} <div *ng for="let item of list3">{{item}} </div></div>

Comment: Ok, As I see you need help in treat the result in your HTML, I have update my previous answer., now with the HTML you need in order to get what you wanted. Check it now and if you have any problem, see it working in the updated stackblitz that I have provided as well. Please, comment that all was OK, bye!

Comment: I would like display result like this picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TjDE.jpg

Comment: But your initial question was about get all the results with your new list (" I have a problem with the new list: I can't have the value for every menu."). How to display it in the way you show now with your new imagen in the comment is possible, but it would be another question... so it's better you write down another one, and add the new code and the new imagen for the desired output.